# override antd component style/className

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to update a antd component style.
I'm using this: https://pro.ant.design/docs/style#override-the-component-style as reference to try updating a component styling but I can't make it to work.

Here's something I'm trying: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wind-kkub0?file=/index.less
I don't understand what I am missing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using scoped styling which is achieved by ejecting your app or installing npm package for loading styled component styles. For this to work, paste your .less code in your index.css file

index.css

```
.ant-select-selection {
  max-height: 51px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.ant-select-selection-search-input {
  background-color: green;
}
.ant-select-item-option-content {
  background-color: orange;
}
.ant-select-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #9068b0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. This seems to work.  However, is the 'index.css' overwrting the global css for the antd component?  I'm not importing any styles from the css.

Comment: @ozn Yes index.css does overwrite css because antd styles are imported in index.js and below that index.css is imported so which ever style files is below that gets high priority.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple overrides in the css?  For example for `ant-select-item-option-content`, I want to have one override with background-color as orange and for another list/dropdown/selection option background-color as blue.  Where ever I have the list/dropdown/selection component, I want to use a different css option for it.