# Multiple overrides to antd component within application

Tags: reactjs, antd

I get how to override an 'antd' component: [override antd component style/className](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294098/override-antd-component-style-classname)

However, I have a situation where I need to have multiple css styles within my application.  For example, within a same page the select option should have different characteristics.  Any suggestions on how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can scope different style with different `className`.

E.g.

css

```
.ant-select-selection-item {
  background-color: green;
}

.abc .ant-select-selection-item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

component

```
...
   <Select defaultValue="lucy" className="abc" style={{ width: 120 }} disabled>
      <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
    </Select>
    <Select defaultValue="lucy" style={{ width: 120 }} loading>
      <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
    </Select>
...
```

Here is an example [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-frost-90cqj?file=/index.js).